# Add Posts page slug to Single Post permalink structure

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know if it's possible to place WordPress Blog POSTS in a unique directory?

In other words:

```
mywebsite.com/blog/Post-A/
mywebsite.com/blog/Post-B/
mywebsite.com/blog/Post-C/
```

I'd like to create `/blog/` which I believe is done by creating a PAGE but that doesn't seem possible.

I've googled this for the last few hours and still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you're probably going to be able to do this without a plugin is by utilizing Categories and a custom permalinks structure.

1. Navigate to Posts > Categories
2. Add a new Category
3. Apply the Category to the desired posts
4. Navigate to Settings > Permalinks
5. Select `Custom Structure` and apply the following structure: `/%category%/%postname%/`

There are also plugins that expand endpoints and routing.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

If your goal is to not have the posts on the front page, you can also set the Blog page to a specific page in Wordpress.

1. Create two new Pages (not to be confused with a post)
2. Navigate to `Settings > Reading`
3. Set `Front page displays` to `A Static Page`
4. Select the Pages to be displayed for the Front page and the Posts page

The Blogroll (Posts page) will then appear under the endpoint of the defined Page's slug.  However, the individual posts permalink will not have the Blogroll Page's slug in the route.

Comment: Thanks - but what I discovered is that if I created a Page and then added that page to the permalinks, that also worked. So, for example, I created a Page called 'blog' and then in Settings > Permalinks I added this: /blog/%postname%/ and that seems to work. Is that not the 'correct' way?